# Change Schema while creating table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an issue later in my process when I want the append tables with a different Datatypes.

I am creating a new table out of an existing table. One column is the **Calenderweek**(KW) which was originally a **STRING**. In order to append my tables later on I need the same datatype for the column.

Is there a way to change the datatype for a column while creating the new table?

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
  MyNewTable
  AS(

  SELECT
    Column_1 AS 
    Column_1_alias,
    **KW_ AS KW,**
    
  FROM
    SourceTable);
```

Comment: Why can't you just use **CAST**? For instance: **cast(KW as NEEDED_DATA_TYPE) as KW**?

Comment: I tried and get this error:
"Value of type INT64 cannot be assigned to KW, which has type STRING"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this Query does is that it only grabs the value of the column KW that contains a number, then checks if the `STRING` value contains a character and removes it from the `STRING`. Finally it `CAST` to the desired value type of the column, so it ends as an `INT`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
 dataset.MyNewTable
 AS(
 
 SELECT
   Column1 AS
   Column1_alias,
   CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(KW,'[^0-9^]','') as INT64) as KW_Alias
 FROM
    `project.dataset.source`
        WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(KW,'[0-9]')
    );
```

Another possible solution is to use the function [REPLACE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#replace) instead of `REGEXP_REPLACE`, to replace the string to a number.

Comment: I actually "solved" it the hard way through changing the initial exported data.

The solution you provided looks good to me although I cant validate it by myself.
Thank you for the solution.